# Incorrect syntax for sql call

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

> Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server error '80040e14'
>
> Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'needa_job_employee_cv'.
>
> /include/server/calls/employee_cv_generic_all.asp, line 6

Basically I use this generic call hundreds of times on this website to call information from dozens of different databases. I just make an ASP object for the SQL call and what database column I am looking for. It works everywhere but the one place, so I assume the problem is with my call.

```
<%cvid = request.querystring("cid")%>
<%=cvid%>
<%call_select = "SELECT * needa_job_employee_cv WHERE employee_cv_id='"& cvid &"'"%>
<%call_fld_1 = "employee_cv_title"%>
<!--#INCLUDE Virtual="/include/server/calls/employee_cv_generic_all.asp" -->
<%getcust_title=getcall_1%>
```

This an example of one that works. Any idea what my problem is? Its probably soemthign obvious.

```
<%call_select = "SELECT * FROM needa_job_employee_cv WHERE employee_cv_id='"& cv &"'"
call_fld_1 = "employee_cv_title"%>
<!--#INCLUDE Virtual="/include/server/calls/employee_cv_generic_all.asp" -->    

<%title_name = getcall_1_ary(j)%>
```

Comment: What's the resulting SQL query? What's the error? What happens? Narrow down the issue to either ASP or SQL. Do some debugging.

Comment: Hello, sql injection vulnerability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
SELECT * FROM needa_job_employee_cv WHERE ...
```

You were missing **FROM** word I think...

Comment: LOL!

Sorry for not spotting that. I knew it was somehtign really stupid.

Comment: @Don: don't mention, you could waste hours on these silly things. I think that everyone caught once on a similar issue in his life :)